# secondary axes 10 times smaller that the main axes using twinx()

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I am producing a plot and I want to make the secondary y-axes 10 times smaller than the main y-axes.

```
ax2 = ax.twinx()
sns.lineplot(data=df["A"], ax=ax)
sns.lineplot(data=df["B"], ax=ax2)
```

is it possible to do define `ax2 = ax.twinx()/10`? how can specifcy that ax2 should be 10 times lower than ax? for example if `ax` goes from 0 to 100, `ax2` should go from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use [`get_ylim`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_ylim.html) and [`set_ylim`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim.html) to re-adjust the limit of `ax2` :

```
ax2 = ax.twinx()
sns.lineplot(data=df["A"], ax=ax)
sns.lineplot(data=df["B"], ax=ax2)
ax2.set_ylim(0, ax.get_ylim()[1]/100) # <- add this line
```

*NB : If you need a view limit from 0 to 1, you need to divide by 100 and not 10.*

Output :

[image]